# How can I determine which specific string has been used in DOS?

Tags: cmd

I would like to rename files and create directories corresponding to the name of files.
However, I'm in trouble with this name of files. I've exported the file names with *.mp3 to text file, and I want to rename all the name of files using

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (test.txt) do rename %%i sameNameAs%%iWithoutMP3
```

If the file name that I want to change is "Beyonce - Halo.mp3", is there any way to use regex? It will be similar to this, if the file name has .mp3 remove it and remain rest of them in English.

Also, is there any way to separate the string with "-" ?
I mean, if the string is "Beyonce - Halo.mp3", I want to create separated String "Beyonce", so that I can create a folder with it.

Please let me know if my description is not enough. I'll fix it. Thanks guys

Comment: Your requirements are not clear at all. It would help if you provided a list of existing file names, followed by what the end result should be. Also, what have you tried? What isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with regex - maybe use VBS script instead of CMD.

Writing and debugging something like you need will be very inefficient in CMD.

Another option is use some tools from [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) ([coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), [regex](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/regex.htm) packages).